# Value of P for $P+\sqrt3Q+\sqrt5R+\sqrt15S=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt3+\sqrt5} $ .I need to know whether the question is wrong and if not how to start it.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Value of P for
$$P+\sqrt3Q+\sqrt5R+\sqrt15S=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt3+\sqrt5} $$

Now I don't even know how to start.I mean I am pretty sure the question is wrong.The above mentioned is the only context.Maybe the variables are all P.But I dont get an answer with even that.
Answer is:$\frac{7}{11}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint you need to rationalize the given surd in such a way that you get an expression of the form $p+\sqrt{3}q+\sqrt{5}r+\sqrt{15}s$. the combination by which you get by clubbing $(1+\sqrt{5})^2-(\sqrt{3})^2$ by multiplying by conjugate two times. Hope you get it.

Comment: Could you just explain the above step a little more clearly.

Comment: Which step you want?

Comment: I did it as you explained it .Thanks .No need for that step now.

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}={\frac {7}{11}}+3/11\,\sqrt {3}-1/11\,\sqrt {5}-2/11\,\sqrt {5}\sqrt {
3}
$$